# What is valid RFC1123 date format

Tags: http, datetime, datetime-format, datetimeoffset, rfc1123

I am working on a service which returns expires header. The service will be working across different timezone. So we need a way to return other timezones than GMT.

I know that the http header have to follow RFC1123 standard date format. So the service returns date like below -

> Fri, 01 Mar 2019 15:00:00 GMT

What I need is return the date in below format.

> Fri, 01 Mar 2019 15:00:00 +0530

Is this a valid date for RFC1123 date format?

Answer (score 11):

I guess you are using the *old* and *obsolete* [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) as reference. Please bear in mind that this document is no longer relevant nowadays and has been replaced with the following documents:

- [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230): Message Syntax and Routing
- [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231): Semantics and Content
- [RFC 7232](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232): Conditional Requests
- [RFC 7233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233): Range Requests
- [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234): Caching
- [RFC 7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235): Authentication

---

According to [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231), HTTP dates must be expressed in GMT. So expressing dates with offsets from UTC **is invalid**.

---

See how the [`Expires`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.3) header is defined in [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.3):

> [**5.3.  Expires**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.3)
>
> The `Expires` header field gives the date/time after which the response is considered stale. [...]
>
> The `Expires` value is an `HTTP-date` timestamp, as defined in [Section 7.1.1.1 of RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.1.1).
>
> ```
>  Expires = HTTP-date
> ```
>
> For example
>
> ```
> Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
> ```

Now see the following quote from [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231):

> [**7.1.1.1.  Date/Time Formats**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.1.1)
>
> Prior to 1995, there were three different formats commonly used by servers to communicate timestamps.  For compatibility with old implementations, all three are defined here.  The preferred format is a fixed-length and single-zone subset of the date and time specification used by the Internet Message Format [RFC5322].
>
> ```
> HTTP-date    = IMF-fixdate / obs-date
> ```
>
> An example of the preferred format is
>
> ```
> Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT    ; IMF-fixdate
> ```
>
> Examples of the two obsolete formats are
>
> ```
> Sunday, 06-Nov-94 08:49:37 GMT   ; obsolete RFC 850 format
> Sun Nov  6 08:49:37 1994         ; ANSI C's asctime() format
> ```
>
> A recipient that parses a timestamp value in an HTTP header field MUST accept all three `HTTP-date` formats.  When a sender generates a header field that contains one or more timestamps defined as `HTTP-date`, the sender MUST generate those timestamps in the `IMF-fixdate` format.
>
> An HTTP-date value represents time as an instance of Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). The first two formats indicate UTC by the three-letter abbreviation for Greenwich Mean Time, GMT, a predecessor of the UTC name; values in the `asctime` format are assumed to be in UTC. [...]

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr:

`Fri, 01 Mar 2019 15:00:00 +0530` **is** RFC 1123-compliant but **not** RFC 2616 (HTTP 1.1)-compliant.

---

RFC 1123 supersedes RFC 882, which originally defined the standard internet date-time formats, and according to the [relevant section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-5) of the latter:

```
date-time   =  [ day "," ] date time        ; dd mm yy
                                            ;  hh:mm:ss zzz

day         =  "Mon"  / "Tue" /  "Wed"  / "Thu"
            /  "Fri"  / "Sat" /  "Sun"

date        =  1*2DIGIT month 2DIGIT        ; day month year
                                            ;  e.g. 20 Jun 82

month       =  "Jan"  /  "Feb" /  "Mar"  /  "Apr"
            /  "May"  /  "Jun" /  "Jul"  /  "Aug"
            /  "Sep"  /  "Oct" /  "Nov"  /  "Dec"

time        =  hour zone                    ; ANSI and Military

hour        =  2DIGIT ":" 2DIGIT [":" 2DIGIT]
                                            ; 00:00:00 - 23:59:59

zone        =  "UT"  / "GMT"                ; Universal Time
                                            ; North American : UT
            /  "EST" / "EDT"                ;  Eastern:  - 5/ - 4
            /  "CST" / "CDT"                ;  Central:  - 6/ - 5
            /  "MST" / "MDT"                ;  Mountain: - 7/ - 6
            /  "PST" / "PDT"                ;  Pacific:  - 8/ - 7
            /  1ALPHA                       ; Military: Z = UT;
                                            ;  A:-1; (J not used)
                                            ;  M:-12; N:+1; Y:+12
            / ( ("+" / "-") 4DIGIT )        ; Local differential
                                            ;  hours+min. (HHMM)
```

The only [change](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123#page-55) that RFC 1123 made to the above is to update `date` to preferably use a 4-digit year, such that the full RFC 1123 specification is effectively:

```
date-time   =  [ day "," ] date time        ; dd mm yy
                                            ;  hh:mm:ss zzz

day         =  "Mon"  / "Tue" /  "Wed"  / "Thu"
            /  "Fri"  / "Sat" /  "Sun"

date        =  1*2DIGIT month 2*4DIGIT      ; day month year
                                            ;  e.g. 20 Jun 1982
                                            ; changed from RFC 822

month       =  "Jan"  /  "Feb" /  "Mar"  /  "Apr"
            /  "May"  /  "Jun" /  "Jul"  /  "Aug"
            /  "Sep"  /  "Oct" /  "Nov"  /  "Dec"

time        =  hour zone                    ; ANSI and Military

hour        =  2DIGIT ":" 2DIGIT [":" 2DIGIT]
                                            ; 00:00:00 - 23:59:59

zone        =  "UT"  / "GMT"                ; Universal Time
                                            ; North American : UT
            /  "EST" / "EDT"                ;  Eastern:  - 5/ - 4
            /  "CST" / "CDT"                ;  Central:  - 6/ - 5
            /  "MST" / "MDT"                ;  Mountain: - 7/ - 6
            /  "PST" / "PDT"                ;  Pacific:  - 8/ - 7
            /  1ALPHA                       ; Military: Z = UT;
                                            ;  A:-1; (J not used)
                                            ;  M:-12; N:+1; Y:+12
            / ( ("+" / "-") 4DIGIT )        ; Local differential
                                            ;  hours+min. (HHMM)
```

So if the software reading your header requires it to be in RFC 1123 format, then yes, `Fri, 01 Mar 2019 15:00:00 +0530` is a completely valid date-time. **However, it is *not* a valid HTTP 1.1 date-time value!**

This is because RFCs 822 and 1123 are concerned primarily with SMTP, not HTTP. It is [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-20) that defines allowed date-time formats for HTTP specifically, and it is far more strict in what is permitted:

```
HTTP applications have historically allowed three different formats
for the representation of date/time stamps:

  Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT  ; RFC 822, updated by RFC 1123
  Sunday, 06-Nov-94 08:49:37 GMT ; RFC 850, obsoleted by RFC 1036
  Sun Nov  6 08:49:37 1994       ; ANSI C's asctime() format

The first format is preferred as an Internet standard and represents
a fixed-length subset of that defined by RFC 1123 [8] (an update to
RFC 822 [9]). The second format is in common use, but is based on the
obsolete RFC 850 [12] date format and lacks a four-digit year.
HTTP/1.1 clients and servers that parse the date value MUST accept
all three formats (for compatibility with HTTP/1.0), though they MUST
only generate the RFC 1123 format for representing HTTP-date values
in header fields. See section 19.3 for further information.
```

RFC 2616 is obsoleted by [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.1.1), which makes the above more explicit:

```
An example of the preferred format is

  Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT    ; IMF-fixdate

Examples of the two obsolete formats are

  Sunday, 06-Nov-94 08:49:37 GMT   ; obsolete RFC 850 format
  Sun Nov  6 08:49:37 1994         ; ANSI C's asctime() format

...

An HTTP-date value represents time as an instance of Coordinated
Universal Time (UTC).
```

In short, if you are writing a strictly HTTP 1.1-compliant application, you **are not permitted** to encode timezone information into a date-time type value; you must convert that value to an absolute (UTC) date-time, and transmit the latter.

Therefore, if you intend for your application to be both RFC 1123-compliant *and* HTTP 1.1-compliant, then the value `Fri, 01 Mar 2019 15:00:00 +0530` is **invalid**. In contrast, the value `Fri, 01 Mar 2019 09:30:00 GMT` (which represents the same point in time), is valid for both specifications.